# How to split a single java program into multiple java programs?

Tags: java

I have a question about splitting a single java program into multiple programs.

Suppose that I have a calculator program, which has the facilities to add, subtract, multiply, divide and find the modulo-division. 
I would like to divide/ split this lengthy program into sub-programs like, add.java for addition, sub.java for subtraction, mul.java for multiplication, and so on.

How do I split it like that, and link each other?

Comment: How are you going to use it after you split it?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a program with multiple classes.  Maybe [this article](http://cephisystems.com/java-article-13-using-multiple-classes-part-1/) will help...

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your real problem is that you don't understand the basics of Java and Object Oriented Design (OOD).  You've just dumped all of your code into a single class, probably using `static` methods and variables all over the place.  (You talk about splitting into sub-programs, and that's a bit of a give-away.)

The Oracle Java Tutorial (or any good Java text book) will explain what a class is, and how to write, compile and run a program consisting of more than one class.

Splitting an existing monolithic class into smaller components is more difficult, 'cos there is no single "right way" to do it.  (And if you understood OOD, that would be patently obvious to you ...)

I recommend that you start by reading some stuff on OOD.  That should give you some insight into what your application design and structure *should* look like.  Once you understand OOD, reading a book on Design Patterns in Java would be helpful too.  However, you will need to understand OOD for Design Patterns to make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You may split add, sub, etc. to different files. But note that, `.java` file name must match class name. For example, if you split add to `add.java`, then in `add.java`, you must have a class named `add`.

After that each `.java` file will be compiled to a `.class` file. When you run, you just need to feed all `.class` files to java, like this:

```
java Calc.class sub.class add.class
```

You may also package all .class files into a .jar file. Then when you run:

```
java Calc.jar
```

Comment: And, how do we connect all these?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of how, but whether you should. Java has the advantage of being a very powerful object-oriented language, but it still has restrictions.

For each program that you want to add, you'll have to create a new class file and a new class.  You still will need a main program, say Calculator.java, which would then have to instantiate versions of the other modules.

```
Add adder = new Add();
Subtract subtracter = new Subtract();
```

Etc. That will end up costing you more time than it's worth, especially if you don't really need to have separate modules for what would appear to be a simple task.

To answer how to do this:

```
Calculator.java //The main program that will import the others.
Add.java
Modulo.java
...etc
```

Assuming that all of these files are together in the one folder, and that you compile them using `javac *.java`, then if `Calculator.java` was to instantiate a new version of `Add.java` as shown above, it would be automatically imported (if that's what your main question is asking).

Unlike C++ or C, you don't need actual import statements.  All java files in one folder are considered to be in one 'package', which is default package.  If you were to declare your own package, then that would be a different matter.